# rails app deploy setting failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, github, capistrano, web-deployment

I'm following the [this site](http://blog.sudobits.com/2013/01/07/how-to-deploy-rails-application-to-vps/).

And I'm in step 6(6. Deploy!).

So I executed below the command in turn.

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -am "add deployment configs"
$ git push master
$ cap deploy:setup
```

And all command was successfully executed.

Next, I tried to `cap deploy` command.

But I get some error.

```
$ cap deploy
  * 2013-06-04 19:19:27 executing `deploy'
    triggering before callbacks for `deploy'
  * 2013-06-04 19:19:27 executing `deploy:check_revision'
WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master
Run `git push` to sync changes.
$
```

So, I try `git push` and I get a message...

```
$ git push
Everything up-to-date
```

...

What is the problem??

I don't know that...

What should I do??

more informateion---

```
$ git branch
* master
$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
$ git remote
origin
```

**Edit:**

I also tried to `$ git push origin master`. And I get a same message that is `nothing to commit (working directory clean)`

**Edit2:**

```
$ git rev-parse HEAD
c3e758f2d47bb0bc126de91560905a1893fe08c6
$ git rev-parse origin/master
c3e758f2d47bb0bc126de91560905a1893fe08c6
```

Comment: What is the output when you run: "git rev-parse origin/master" and "git rev-parse HEAD" that is what capistrano is checking.

Comment: output is same... :-(

Answer (score 4):

Check your current branch and deploy.file.

In the deploy.file, it could exist the following code snippet:

```
task :check_revision, roles: :web do
   unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
     puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
     puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
     exit
   end
end
```

So you must be on the same branch set in this code.

To fix, change the following line:

```
 unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/${YOUR_CURRENT_BRANCH}`
```

Answer (score 1):

The following worked nice for/to me.
Try:

```
git remote show origin
```

If you get an error, ask for all remotes:

```
git remote -v
```

and set remote origin:

```
git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:xyz/abc.git
```

Now 'show origin' will provide the correct answer:

```
git remote show origin
```

Comment: This did it more than other answers

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
git push origin master
```

Looks like you may not be pushing the code back to the remote repo.

You should be able to edit your .git/config file so in the future you can just type "git push"

Answer (score 0):

I think your deploy.rb file is not set up correctly.  Check line 14 where your repository is set up.  Make sure it matches your github repo.

If that doesn't work, try this: after `task :check_revision, roles: :web do` add these lines:

```
puts `git rev-parse HEAD`
puts `git rev-parse origin/master`
```

Hopefully that will give you some more info and you can post the results.